# Broken binding when creating element in SVG namespace [with JSFiddle]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, svg, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive for rendering rectangles in `<svg>` elements.

```
app.directive('drRect', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // #makeNode simply creates a DOM node using 
            // `document.createElementNS` so that it can be appended to an SVG 
            // element. It also assigns any attributes on the directive. See the
            // linked fiddle for definition.
            var shape = makeNode('rect', element, attrs);
            var elementShape = angular.element(shape);
            element.replaceWith(shape);

            // Not sure what this is doing. It comes from: http://goo.gl/ZoYpQv
            attrs.$observe('value', function (value) {
                scope['value'] = parseInt(value, 10);
                $compile(shape)(scope);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I'm using this directive inside an `<svg>` tag to render rectangles. I also have a list of inputs which you would expect to be bound to the `x` attribute of each respective `<rect>`. However, changing the value of `x` doesn't change the corresponding attribute on the rectangle (`x` stands for the distance of the rectangle from the left side of the svg). You can test this system [with this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtuite/SWv2s/1/).

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <svg height="200" width="200">
        <dr-rect ng-repeat="shape in shapes" fill="{{shape.fill}}" height="{{shape.height}}" width="{{shape.width}}" x="{{shape.x}}" y="{{shape.y}}"></dr-rect>
    </svg>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="shape in shapes">
            <input type="text" ng-model="shape.x"/> {{shape.x}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I suspect that binding is being lost when I replace the element in the `link` function.

```
element.replaceWith(shape);
```

You can see the type of behaviour I expect [in this other JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtuite/SWv2s/2/) where changing the value in the input does indeed change the value in the directive.

How can I get the same behaviour with the SVG element?

---

**EDIT**: I got it working in a hackish way. Basically I can `$watch` the model attributes and manually reset attributes whenever an attributes value changes.

```
scope.$watch('shape', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  for (var key in newVal) {
    if (newVal.hasOwnProperty(key) && isPublic(key, newVal[key])) {
      if (newVal[key] !== oldVal[key]) {
        elementShape.attr(key, newVal[key]);
      }
    }
  }
}, true);
```

This doesn't feel right to me though. I'm basically re-writing the attribute binding system manually. I don't think I should have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a custom directive.  Just put the  elements in the ng-repeat.  You'll need to prefix all of your attributes with ng-attr to avoid JS errors before Angular can fill the values in the rects. See the updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/SWv2s/9/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <svg height="200" width="200" ng-repeat="shape in shapes" ng-cloak>
        <rect ng-attr-fill="{{shape.fill}}" ng-attr-height="{{shape.height}}" ng-attr-width="{{shape.width}}" ng-attr-x="{{shape.x}}" ng-attr-y="{{shape.y}}"></rect>
    </svg>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="shape in shapes">
            <input type="text" ng-model="shape.x"/> {{shape.x}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.shapes = [{
        x: 12,
        y: 13,
        height: 34,
        width: 42,
        fill: '#222'
    }];
}]);
```